# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.client'

Tags: python-3.x

I got this error in in Python3.6 **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.client'**,i tried pip3.6 install --upgrade google-api-python-client,But I don't know how to fix

Please tell me how to fix,

Thanks

Comment: check that you're activating the env. if yes .. uninstall then re-install it

Comment: thank you Raouf,i tried but not fixed

Answer (score 5):

Use below code, this worked for me:

pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client